# OpenSeadragon Magnification Strategy for Lens

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I'm working on some tooling for an OpenSeadragon-powered app that allows a user to apply different levels of magnification inside a "lens" area. My strategy has been to create two Viewers: one visible at current zoom, another hidden at the magnified zoom level:

[image: Example lens magnification]

The good news is that things work, but at some cost to performance (esp when I try to do any pixel manipulation to image data). For anyone familiar with OpenSeadragon, is it a bad strategy to build two viewers? I can provide some code for context, but I think this might be a conceptual question.

Also for those of you familiar with the source code, it looks to me like `requestAnimationFrame` is applied to OpenSeadragon animations from functions like `zoomTo()` or `panTo()` - is that a fair reading?

Any insights welcome! Thanks! Be blessed!

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a reasonable strategy. Another thing to try would be to have a single viewer with multiple copies of the image directly in the viewer (see http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/multi-image/). You could set the "magnified" image as being bigger, and move it around within the viewer in response to the user's mouse movement. You can even give it a round clipping region via setCroppingPolygons. I don't know if that would be better or worse performance than what you're currently doing… Just brainstorming.

As for requestAnimationFrame, OpenSeadragon has one such loop for all animation. It also uses requestAnimationFrame for some utility functions, like fading buttons and continuing to zoom while the user holds down the mouse button on the zoom button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @iangilman - didn't expect an answer from a creator :^). I'll try what you've mentioned, though some recent improvements have made scroll magnification buttery smooth.  Also thanks for the update on the animation cycle, and thanks++ for building this incredible tool!

Comment: Happy to help when I can… Thank you for the kind words :-)